# Dynamic Filter for Dates and add totals to last row of table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to make my code dynamic by adding a filter to only add values from current year to previous 7 years , so if in my example the year is 2019 . then it would show in order 2012 to 2019.

I am also trying to add a totals to the output data in last column after Dec , so in the example below 2012 row of values would have an additional column after Month Dec , with the sum of Jan to Dec values , which would be    8435 + 31 + 18 = 8484

```
Year    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
   2012 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8435 31 18
   2013 27  21  30  12  31  17  21  9   19  25  18  17
   2014 31  21  16  18  23  31  19  21  12  24  13  15
   2015 20  14  44  37  23  13  37  26  32  57  25  19
   2016 10  15  12  11  18  12  16  44  27  41  29  12
   2017 15  10  12  13  10  13  21  26  11  18  14  7
   2018 9   15  9   29  10  12  12  19  13  20  14  5
   2019 15  10  10  12  5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

(
year(db.org.DateCreated) ='2012'
or year(db.org.DateCreated) ='2013'
or year(db.org.DateCreated) ='2014'
or year(db.org.DateCreated) ='2015'
or year(db.org.DateCreated) ='2016'
or year(db.org.DateCreated) ='2017'
or year(db.org.DateCreated) ='2018'
or year(db.org.DateCreated) ='2019'
)

select year(db.org.DateCreated) [Year], 
sum(case when month(db.org.DateCreated) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Jan,
sum(case when month(db.org.DateCreated) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Feb,
sum(case when month(db.org.DateCreated) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Mar,
sum(case when month(db.org.DateCreated) = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Apr,
sum(case when month(db.org.DateCreated) = 5 then 1 else 0 end) May,
sum(case when month(db.org.DateCreated) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) Jun,
sum(case when month(db.org.DateCreated) = 7 then 1 else 0 end) Jul,
sum(case when month(db.org.DateCreated) = 8 then 1 else 0 end) Aug,
sum(case when month(db.org.DateCreated) = 9 then 1 else 0 end) Sep,
sum(case when month(db.org.DateCreated) = 10 then 1 else 0 end) Oct,
sum(case when month(db.org.DateCreated) = 11 then 1 else 0 end) Nov,
sum(case when month(db.org.DateCreated) = 12 then 1 else 0 end) Dec
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a CTE to generate the monthly totals, for each year, then query that CTE to find the sum across months.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        YEAR(db.org.DateCreated) [Year],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(db.org.DateCreated) = 1 THEN 1 END) Jan,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(db.org.DateCreated) = 2 THEN 1 END) Feb,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(db.org.DateCreated) = 3 THEN 1 END) Mar,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(db.org.DateCreated) = 4 THEN 1 END) Apr,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(db.org.DateCreated) = 5 THEN 1 END) May,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(db.org.DateCreated) = 6 THEN 1 END) Jun,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(db.org.DateCreated) = 7 THEN 1 END) Jul,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(db.org.DateCreated) = 8 THEN 1 END) Aug,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(db.org.DateCreated) = 9 THEN 1 END) Sep,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(db.org.DateCreated) = 10 THEN 1 END) Oct,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(db.org.DateCreated) = 11 THEN 1 END) Nov,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(db.org.DateCreated) = 12 THEN 1 END) Dec
    WHERE YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(db.org.DateCreated) BETWEEN 0 AND 7
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY
        YEAR(db.org.DateCreated)
)

SELECT
    Year,
    Jan,
    Feb,
    Mar,
    Apr,
    May,
    Jun,
    Jul,
    Aug,
    Sep,
    Oct,
    Nov,
    Dec,
    (Jan + Feb + Mar + Apr + May + Jun + Jul + Aug + Sep + Oct + Nov + Dec) AS total
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    year;
```

Note that I replaced your calls to `SUM` with `COUNT`, which is a bit more terse and easy to read.

Comment: Thanks I already had the group by added , and my code works , but I needed to add another column at the end for totals for each year. and also make the year filter dynamic , as it would not work correct next year as it has static dates added

Comment: Thanks that worked , it has added the Totals column. Is there a way to make the other code dynamic by always filtering by last 8years. so next year it would be 2013 to 2020

Comment: Yes, just add a `WHERE` clause to the CTE restricting the date to no later than this year and no earlier than 7 years prior.

Comment: how would I write that please , as I am still in only my second month of learning SQL